# Passing array from external js.file to route

Tags: jquery, node.js, routes, express

I'm working on an application built on Node.js with Express which shows images from a database.

Right now i'm working on the functionality of creating albums from the images that's displayed, which is done by clicking on images. The images id's and names are then pushed into an array in an external js-file. When the user is done with adding images to the album, he clicks on a button (inside a form), which theb gets handled by a route.

The question is how can I access the array inside external js-file in the route? Is it even possible?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

I've tried to implement [@andy s solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10311581/937624), **but I get a 404 in the console**. I guess I'm doing something wrong here?

external.js (included in the header of the html file):

```
$('#saveAlbum').click(function (){          
    $.post('http://localhost:3000/createAlbum', { arr: ['val1', 'val2'] })
});
```

albumController.js:

```
app.post('/createAlbum', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.arr);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need to pass data from client side to Express, you could send it with jquery's $.post() to a special route:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer();

app.configure(function(){
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
});

app.post('/for_receive_array', function(req, res) {
  //req.body - body passes your array
});

app.listen(8000);
```

Sorry if I did not understand your purpose. It is better to see your code.

Comment: I've tried it out, but I don't get it to work. How should the $.post() code look like to be able to send to the route?

Comment: for example, `$.post('http://localhost:8000/for_receive_array', { arr: ['val1', 'val2'] })`. To access it on server: `req.body.arr`. Don't forget `app.listen(PORT)` on server. I've added it in answer above

Comment: I've tried to implement the code, but it doesn't seem to work. Please see my updated question. I suppose something is wrong?

Comment: Tried it. Still gets "POST /createAlbum 404". Strange :/

Comment: Are you sure that server is running in specified port without errors? Try to add to the server `app.get('/', function(req, res) {console.log('received /'); res.send('ok')});`

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Works now. Thanks A LOT!